# Connect to Windows Server 2012 on specific ports

Tags: firewall, windows-server-2012, ports

> Try to connect to your computer on ports (135÷139,445), for example by
>   connecting to a shared folder (C$). You can use "net use" command.

Hey, I'm making security exercises (Firewall stuff), but I'm completely stuck on this point. I have my physical computer and virtual machine (Windows Server 2012 on VMware). I have turned off all my Inbound and Outbound Rules in Firewall and now trying to test connection to review logs, but I can't solve this one. Any advice?

Comment: Hint: `net share` and `net use /?`

Comment: @DavidPostill yeah, i was trying to find some informations about net use, but it looks really unclear for me. I tried command `net use c: \\192.168.229.132 /user:administrator [pass]`.

Comment: You need to use an unused drive letter and a sharename, eg `net use z: \\computername\sharename password /USER:[domainname\]username`

Comment: See [net use](http://ss64.com/nt/net_use.html) - Map a drive letter to a remote server/share.

Comment: @DavidPostill computername\sharename i understand it is `192.168.229.132\c$`, but i dont understand what is domainname for my username

Comment: The domain name is optional and only required if you are in a domain. That's why it is in `[]`.

Comment: @DavidPostill But what about ports then? I see net use is working on port number 139 and 445 in default, but am i right?

Comment: [Difference between NetBIOS and SMB](//superuser.com/q/694469)